# WCS elevation with Cesium + Geoserver

Tags: gdal, cesium

I'm trying to develop an offline demonstrator showing hi-resolution bathymetry data using Cesium 1.11 and Geoserver.

I've merged a number of 1/3 arc second areas around Puerto-Rico from NOAA bathymetry viewer using gdal_merge.py, for example [San Juan, PR 1/3 arc-second](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/dem/squareCellGrid/download/1601). This appears to setup correctly in GeoServer using layer preview.

[image: layer preview]

I'm loading the data via [WCSTerrainProvider](https://github.com/xlhomme/WCSTerrainProvider), however only half the globe is shown.

```
var wcsTerrain = new Cesium.WCSTerrainProvider({
    service : "WCS",
    url : "/geoserver/wcs",
    layerName : "puerto-rico",
    waterMask : false
});
```

[image: Half globe]

I've narrowed the problem down to the WCS "Describe Coverage" response from geoserver.

- GEBCO 30-arc second data with global coverage behaves correctly i.e. -180 to +180, -90 to +90
- If I force the coverage of the 1/3 second data to be -180 to +180 using gdal_translate then full globe is seen.

My question

- Does anyone have any examples of how to use Cesium with a high-resolution subset of terrain data.
- Is it possible to use GDAL tooling to "render" the 1/3 data into a GeoTIFF that covers the entire globe without using excessive amounts of disk space?

Comment: I'm trying the same method to try to display terrain in GeoTIFF format in Cesium.  Are you using 16-bit signed integer GeoTIFF to serve the terrain behind your Geoserver?  Or 32-bit float?   Do both work?

Comment: I think signed 16 bit integer, not near computer at mo,  will check on Monday,  I did get it all working in the end...

Comment: did you figure this out?